# using WiFly with ws websockets

Tags: node.js, websocket, arduino

I have been trying to figure out a way to connect a WiFly from an Arduino to send some accelerometer data to my node.js server. Currently the way that I have it worked out is having three servers:

1. Http >> This is for clients purposes
2. Net server >> This is basically for TCP request, this is how my server receives the information from 3. WS websockets >> this takes the data from the Net server and streams it to the client side.

Here is the code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var url = require('url');
var net = require('net');
var sensorData;
var message = {
  "data": ''
}
var newValue,
  oldValue,
  diff;
//Settings
var HTTP_PORT = 9000;
var NET_PORT = 9001;
var WS_PORT = 9002;
//Server
var mimeTypes = {
  "html": "text/html",
  "jpeg": "image/jpeg",
  "jpg": "image/jpeg",
  "png": "image/png",
  "js": "text/javascript",
  "css": "text/css"
};
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var fileToLoad;
  if (req.url == '/') {
    fileToLoad = 'index.html';
  } else {
    fileToLoad = url.parse(req.url).pathname.substr(1);
  }

  console.log('[HTTP] :: Loading :: ' + 'frontend/' + fileToLoad);
  var fileBytes;
  var httpStatusCode = 200;
  fs.exists('frontend/' + fileToLoad, function (doesItExist) {
    if (!doesItExist) {
      console.log('[HTTP] :: Error loading :: ' + 'frontend/' + fileToLoad);
      httpStatusCode = 404;
    }
    var fileBytes = fs.readFileSync('frontend/' + fileToLoad);
    var mimeType = mimeTypes[path.extname(fileToLoad).split('.')[1]];
    res.writeHead(httpStatusCode, {
      'Content-type': mimeType
    });
    res.end(fileBytes);
  });
  // console.log("[INIT] Server running on HTTP Port");
}).listen(HTTP_PORT);

proxy.on("close", function(){
  console.log("Connection has closed");
});

proxy.on("end", function(){
  console.log("Connection has ended");
 });
var socket;
var clients = [];
var socketObject;
var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
  socketObject = socket;
  socket.name = socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort;
  clients.push(socket);
  console.log(socket);
  socket.write("HTTP/1.1 101", function () {
    console.log('[CONN] New connection: ' + socket.name + ', total clients: ' + clients.length);
  });
  socket.setEncoding('utf8');
  socket.on('error', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
  socket.on('end', function () {
    console.log('[END] Disconnection: ' + socket.name + ', total clients: ' + clients.length);
  });
  socket.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('[RECV from ' + socket.remoteAddress + "] " + data);
    oldValue = newValue;
    newValue = data;
    diff = Math.abs(newValue) - Math.abs(oldValue);
    console.log(Math.abs(newValue) + '-' + Math.abs(oldValue));
    message.data = Math.abs(diff);
    console.log('[SAVED] ' + message.data);
  });
});
server.listen(NET_PORT, function () {
  console.log("[INIT] Server running on NET server port", NET_PORT);
});
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server,
  wss = new WebSocketServer({
    port: WS_PORT
  });
wss.on('connection', function (ws) {
  // ws.send(JSON.stringify(message));
  setInterval(function () {
    updateXData(ws)
  }, 500);
});


function updateXData(ws) {
  var newMessage = {
    "data": ""
  }
  newMessage.data = message.data
  ws.send(JSON.stringify(newMessage));
}
```

So the question is: Is there a cleaner way to do this just by using ws to handle the data from the WiFly and then sending it to the client?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this will suit you and might be new to you but you could make use of MQTT, there are free brokers available which are very good and its relatively easy to set up and implement with Arduino equipped with WiFly Shield.

http://mqtt.org/

Hope this helps somewhat!